# Button on click do not change screen in kivymd

Tags: python, kivy, python-3.7, kivy-language

I'm new to kivy and don't getting why my button in navigation drawer do not changing to another class in kivymd 
there is a button in class ContentNavigationDrawer on click I want it to change to another screen
I dont get why it is not changing I already read the documentation about ScreenManager but still not able to understand

this is my code
main.py

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class AboutUs(Screen):
    pass


class Share(FloatLayout):
    data = {
        "facebook": "Facebook",
        "whatsapp": "WhatsApp",
        "instagram": "Instagram",
    }

    def callback(self, instance):
        print('Hello')
        print(instance.icon)



class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    def hllo(self):
        print('Hello though')


class MainScreen(FloatLayout):

    def quote(self, *args):
        self.quote_text = 'I often think that the night is more alive and more richly colored than  
                                    the day. -Vincent van Gogh '
    quote_text = StringProperty()


class TtApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.title = "Story A Day"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue"  # "Purple", "Red"
        main = MainScreen()
        Clock.schedule_once(main.quote, 5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TtApp().run()
```

and this my main.kv file

```
Screen:
    AboutUs:

    MainScreen:

    NavigationLayout:

        ScreenManager:

            Screen:

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'

                    MDToolbar:
                        title: "Quote"
                        anchor_title: 'left'
                        elevation: 10
                        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state()]]
                        mode: "free-center"

                    Widget:



        MDNavigationDrawer:
            title: 'Quote'
            id: nav_drawer
            swipe_distance: 10

            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                id: content_drawer


<ContentNavigationDrawer>
    name: 'main'
    background_color: 2, 3, 4, 5
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: "8dp"
    spacing: "8dp"

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: "right"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: avatar.height

        Image:
            id: avatar
            size_hint: None, None
            size: "56dp", "56dp"
            source: "data/logo/kivy-icon-256.png"

        MDLabel:
            anchor_y: 'left'
            text: "[b]Story A Day[/b]"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            markup: True
            font_style: "H4"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]

    MDRaisedButton:
        md_bg_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
        text: 'You Can'
        on_release: root.hllo()

    MDRaisedButton:
        text: 'Click Me'
        on_release: print('Hell')

    MDLabel:
        text: 'Story A Day' 
        font_style: "Button"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]

    OneLineAvatarListItem:
        text: "About Us"

        IconLeftWidget:
            icon: "information"

    Button:
        text: 'hello'
        on_release: app.root.manager.current = 'Abt'


    ScrollView:


<MainScreen>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1 
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    Label:
        id: quote
        text: root.quote_text
        font_size: '20sp'
        size: self.texture_size
        pos_hint: {'x': -0.2, 'y': 0.27}


<AboutUs>:
    name: 'Abt'
    Label:
        text: 'Hellooo'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put ScreenManger as rule widget and put your MainScreen at first and in the last put your AboutUs class.

Answer (score 0):

Put all your screen inside the ScreenManager first. so the screenmanager can control the change screen